# Node js - send grid issue on sending basic email

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Node js - send grid issue on sending basic email

I've setup my node js server and need help with the setup.

**Error "cant set headers"**

**This is my code:**

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')('IHaveAKey');

  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

  router.get('/welcomeEmail/:email/:name', function(req, res) {
    var subject = 'Hello' + req.params.name;

    sendgrid.send({
      to:       'test@hotmail.co.uk',
      from:     'noreply@test.com',
      subject:  'Test',
      text:     'Welcome'
    }, function(err, json) {
      if (err) { return res.send("Error");}    
      return res.send("Sent");
    });

    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

**This is my error:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triying to send response from server 2 times:

1) `res.sendStatus(200);`

2) `res.send("Sent");`

Leave one of this line and everything start to be ok

Comment: that fixed the console error. thanks for that. However, send grid returns an error still. Error I get is: "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked"

Comment: you specify error as ``Error "cant set headers"``. Is solved.

Comment: I know get this error message:  "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked" - any ideas?