# SendGrid API Key is not working. "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked"

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

SendGrid seems to be preventing my node js server from sending emails.

I get this error message in the response on sending off an email:

> The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked

I have an API key setup as well and have followed the documentation.

Comment: This would be easier to debug with some code ;)

Comment: Here's my code for this from my previous ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788083/node-js-send-grid-issue-on-sending-basic-email

Comment: Can you recheck your apikey, I just modified mine to be incorrect and got the issue "[Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked]". Double check that and let me know.

Comment: I've doubled checked and that seems fine

Comment: @kunalbatra - any other ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking it could be an account issue, can you email support@sendgrid.com with your username and let them know the error.

Comment: Are you using the API key or the API Key ID?

Approximately how many characters long is the key you are using?

The value you are using, is it less than 30 characters or more then 60 characters?

Comment: The value of 'IHaveAKey' should be the value of the key when you generated it (see screenshot for example: http://imgur.com/DjhjnXu ) not the api key name and not the api key id (see screenshot of what not to use: http://imgur.com/QGdamZh )

Comment: I use the Api key - the guid

Comment: I just double checked and I'm using the "API Key ID"

Comment: When you copy the API Key and paste it, there is an extra space coming in front by default. Please make sure to remove the extra spaces.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to use the API KEY GENERATED

[image]

DO NOT USE the API KEY ID

[image]

Sendgrid only displays the generated key once when you create it. [image]

If you didn't record it somewhere when you created the key you'll need to create a new key and then you'll probably want to delete the old key since it would be useless if you don't know what it is.

FYI: The API key in the screenshot above is already deleted. I deleted it right away so please don't worry about me leaking that key.

Comment: I see, where can I find that? I'm searching send grid for it

Comment: Sendgrid only displays the generated key once when you create it. If you didn't record it somewhere when you created the key you'll need to create a new key.

Comment: They wont let me on the free plan. Doesnt even let me delete it either

Comment: I've emailed them so hopefully they sort my account

Comment: Click 'Delete' a couple of times. It was glitchy for me two. I clicked 'Delete' half a dozen times, waited a minute then refreshed the page and it was finally deleted.

Comment: Hmmm... I have a free plan too and I was able to create multiple keys. Try disabling any adblockers and make sure that you assign some access to the newly created API Key (Full Access to Mail Send).

Comment: Got it working now. I was logged in with incorrect permissions

Comment: OH! God! I've spent 2 hours searching for my error! :( That is a shity interface!

Comment: hey i didnt even create an api key or id, how to do that, and it didnt prompt me to save anything too, please help

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer and JAVA oriented.. But I simply copied the docs and didn't notice..

```
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
```

I just put my key in there and **didn't see the getEnv**.  Silly of course.. but when trying to get things to work quickly...

Comment: ```new SendGrid("SENDGRID_API_KEY");```  That worked for me. System.getenv didnt work.

Comment: Yes, your code just needed to be like :                                                            
 SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY"); without the System.getenv() method! wonder why they have it in the docs anyway

Answer (score 4):

For me I just had to generate a new API key. For some weird reason the former API key has become invalid, so I also added an alert for this case

Comment: This was the case for me as well. Do you have any idea why the former API key became invalid? Also, what kind of alert have you set up?

Comment: Have no idea why this was the case and it's more than half a year ago, so sorry can't provide any more useful info

Answer (score 2):

In Sendgrid v3, I had the similar issue when using env variable in Node JS. If I use env variable, I get the above issue. But if I drop the string into the require process, it works.

**Doesn't Work:**

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

**Works**

```
var sg = require('sendgrid')('SG.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Replace SG.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX with API Key Generated (which you can only see once during key generation).

**EDIT**

Note : Make sure you don't save this to public repository. If you do anyone can use your API Key and also your account will be suspended by Sendgrid team temporarily until you remove it from repository.

Comment: This solution works for me, but do you have any idea of how to fix this. This is not a good solution for developer who uses the .env file.

Comment: I got the same error. So if anyone will get into same issue - double check your's .env file. The key should not be in quotes "" or any other separators. Should look something like: SENDGRID_API_KEY = your_key_here

Answer (score 2):

- If you are using `node js`,
- make sure you have the `require('dotenv').config()`line inside the file that needs the `sendgrid/nodemailer` module.
- Without it, the *sendgrid transporter* will have an `undefined` value instead of the `api_key`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to debug the connection by using telnet and kept getting rejected.

Turns out that these two are not equivalent, `echo` will include `\n` in the encoded string.

```
echo 'apikey' | base64
printf 'apikey' | base64
```

So yeah, make sure you don't include the newline in the API key.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. I'm using SendGrid in kubernetes and needed to store the apikey value encrypted using base64. I've been going crazy about this for days, and this is exactly what it was happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

1. Install the dotenv package: **npm i dotenv**
2. Go to the earliest entry point of your application(i.e index.js) and put this at the top:

   **const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();**
3. Create a .env file and add **SENDGRID_API_KEY=<YOUR_API_KEY>**. NO quotes '' or "".
4. In your file which you use sendgrid, add this to the top:

   **const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');**

   **sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);**

Done.

Comment: I did the integration like this and had the same error

Answer (score 0):

It might be late for an answer but for people who are getting the same problem in spring boot

it might be caused at initialization when you are using env or property value

i was initializing the variable in the constructor before the value was loaded by spring and it was giving the same output. so either initialize it in the method you are calling the SendGrid function or do it after values are loaded

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,
api_key: `${process.env.SENDGRIDAPIKEY}`

try,
api_key: "" + `${process.env.SENDGRIDAPIKEY}` + ""

worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

For me; I've just created a new API key and then it works again.
I'm %100 sure it was working with no any code change.

Maybe it is an issue with SendGrid or some sort of security action from SendGrid.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, it disappeared after I verified my email address and enabled 2FA.