# Sendgrid node.js error 535 bad username/password

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, sendgrid

When attempting to send an email through node.js, I used the example from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs-example. I have changed the sendgrid username and password in the javascript files and I know that they are correct but the function still responds with error 535. How do I fix this or is there any easier way to send emails with javascript or node.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an easier way. Create an API key and then use:

```
var sendgrid   = require('sendgrid')(sendgrid_apikey);
```

The API Key value will be of this format: 'xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

And see the following question for clarification on how to create and get the key:

[SendGrid API Key not working. "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789622/send-grid-seems-to-be-preventing-my-node-js-server-sending-emails/34798357#34798357)